# Condition Based on Page Breaking

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals

I am working on some software to automatically format documents to comply with strict court rules. Under these rules, it sometimes matters whether a given piece of text appears on the front cover or on the inside cover (second PDF page). Is there some way to test whether the text that is about to be set is on the same page as a reference (most helpful) or on a given numbered page (probably good enough)? For example, could I program certain text to appear only if it fits on the cover? Or could I have "continued on next page" if a single environment spans two pages?

Comment: You can determine the size of text using a savebox, such as `\setbos\mybox=\vbox{...)` or `\savebox\mybox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth} ...\end{minipage}}`.  See also `lrbox` (environment).  Thye height is given by `\ht\mybox` and the depth (distance below baseline) by `\dp\mybox`.  The amount of space left on the page (updated between paragraqphs)  is given by `\pagegoal -\pagetotal` (except at the start of a new page).

Comment: oops, `\setbox`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo. This is very helpful. Is there some way to tell whether the text is on the first or second page? The code you gave would let me test whether the text is at the bottom of one page or the top of the next, but it would not let me tell whether it is on the bottom of page 1 or the bottom of page 2.

Comment: The page counter (`\value{page}`) is not absolutely reliable,.  At the very bottom of the page addng any text at all might move it to the next page.  The ifoddpage package is useful here with `\checkoddpage` and  `\oddpage@page`.

Comment: See also the needspace package.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo. I had not thought about \checkoddpage but that's a great idea! I think \checkoddpage and \pagegoal -\pagetotal together should work. I really appreciate your help.